# Creating pull request and adding reviewers, workItems to it programatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure

I created a pull request using this statement:

```
pullRequest = gitClient.CreatePullRequestAsync(gitPullRequest, shrdRepo.Id, 
                         supportsIterations: true, cancellationToken: token).Result;
```

I'm trying to add the reviewer and work items to it.
For reviewer adding tried to identify the reviewer using below statement. But I'm getting an exception:

```
IdentityHttpClient identityHttpClient = new IdentityHttpClient(new Uri(c_collectionUri), creds);
IdentitiesCollection identitiesPerAlias = identityHttpClient.ReadIdentitiesAsync(IdentitySearchFilter.MailAddress, mail, cancellationToken:token).Result;
```

Exception is:

```
Exception when looking for vsts identity for alias xyzxyz.com. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssResourceNotFoundException: API resource location 28010c54-d0c0-4c89-a5b0-1c9e188b9fb7 is not registered on https://dev.azure.com/xyz.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<CreateRequestMessageAsync>d__34.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__28`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.Client.IdentityHttpClient.<ReadIdentitiesAsyncInternal>d__42.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at AzureDevOpsSample.Program.<SearchForReviewerVstsIdentity>d__4.MoveNext() in D:\Projects\tools_release_notes\tools-ReleaseNotes_PR_Working\createPrForSharedRepo\Program.cs:line 349
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssResourceNotFoundException: API resource location 28010c54-d0c0-4c89-a5b0-1c9e188b9fb7 is not registered on https://dev.azure.com/xyz.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<CreateRequestMessageAsync>d__34.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__28`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.Client.IdentityHttpClient.<ReadIdentitiesAsyncInternal>d__42.MoveNext()<---
```

Can anyone suggest me to identify the reviewer and add work items to pull request?